# c# mvc dynamically create controller from string name - eval?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to create a new instance of a controller, via a string name.  In classic ASP I'd do an eval, but how to do it in c#?

eg:

If I wanted to create an instance of the "AccountController, normally I'd write:

```
var Acc = new AccountController();
```

Now if the controller name is only available as a string, how could I instantiate the object?

eg,

```
var controllerName = "AccountController";

var acc = new eval(controllerName)();
```

Thank you for any help!

Frank

Comment: This is what ASP.NET MVC does under the hood to match URLs against Controllers. Are you sure you can't leave this to the framework itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your controller is within the assembly you just need a class name, otherwise you need a fully qualified name (namespace *and* assembly). You would do it using reflection. Something like:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("NameOfController");
var  c = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

There are other ways, but all involve reflection (`System.Reflection`).

Answer (score 5):

An IOC container would allow this functionality.  When you register your controller type, just provide a name.  Then you can return a fully instantiated object from the controller by providing the name.

Also, most IOC containers will allow you to automatically register types base on an interface or base class, so you wouldn't even need to register all of your controllers manually.

An example in [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

```
var b = new ContainerBuilder();
b.Register<AccountController>().As<IController>().Named("AccountController");
var c = b.Build();

var controller = c.Resolve<IController>("AccountController");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) but you need to know both the name of the type and of the assembly containing it (or meet other conditions).  That shouldn't be too hard since all of the controllers are in a single assembly.  I'd really like to know why you think you need to do this, though.  I've done a couple of fairly large projects in MVC and can't think of any reason outside of unit testing where I needed to create a controller at all.  The MVC pattern provides good separation of concerns and creating a controller (from a string, no less) smells like a pattern violation.